# Optimal improper vertex-coloring of graph with weighted edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings

I have an undirected graph with weighted edges. I want to color the vertices with a given $k$ colors. Let's assume there is **no** proper coloring with $k$ colors such that adjacent nodes will always have different colors. I want to find the improper color assignments that would minimize the sum of weights of edges between nodes of the same color.

I have looked through many papers looking at improper coloring algorithms but cannot find this particular variant. [This paper](ftp://ftp-sop.inria.fr/mascotte/Publications/ABG+11b.pdf) looks at something similar, but instead minimizes $k$ given a threshold on the sum of weights. Instead, I want to fix $k$ and *minimize* the sum of weights. Does anybody know the best approach for this?

Full citation to the paper:

J. Araujo, J.-C. Bermond, F. Giroire, F. Havet, D. Mazauric, R. Modrzejewski, Weighted improper coloring, Research report 7590, INRIA, Sophia Antipolis, 2011.

Comment: Your problem is NP-hard. Are you interested in approximation algorithms? Heuristics?

Comment: I think you should be able to use binary search on the threshold combined with the techniques of that paper, to get what you want.

Comment: I would be fine with approximations or maybe a greedy algorithm if necessary.

Comment: Do you require some guarantees on the solution quality? Probably metaheuristics would be good on the problem, but can you clarify what you are hoping for more precisely?